# Longer running task using schedule timer

Tags: java, timer

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

class Test {
  boolean in_state;
}
class Processor {
  Timer timer;
  Test test;
  Processor(Test test) {
    this.test = test;
    init();
  }
  private init() {
    this.timer = new Timer();
    this.timer.schedule(new ProcessTask(), 0, 1000/20);
  }
  private class ProcessTask extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
        if(test.in_state) {
          return;//skip
        }
        test.in_state = true;//start flag
        if(meetsCondition()) {
         //process possibly longer
         //make sure next scheduled task execution is delayed/skipped during until this task execution is finished
        }
        test.in_state = false;//end flag
      }
    }
 }
```

What I need to make sure is that the next execution of Process Task happens when the previous one is finished (which will take longer when a meetsCondition() occurs).

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Why are you using multiple threads if you want to force tasks to run in serial?

Comment: indeed, I just noticed the TimerTask is a separate thread

Comment: hmm...timer.schedule only takes TimerTask and run method is required. any other solution I can implement?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: I seem to have found what I'm looking for. The ScheduledExecutorService gives me ability to make run the execution in a single thread, and thus make sure it executes sequentially.